# How can I stop my cat from jumping on top of my car?

Tags: cats

I live with three cats.

From time to time some of them jump on top of my car in the garage. The problem is that the car paint gets scratched (its getting worse everyday) and a lot of cats steps (footprints) goes to the paint, so I have to wash the cars every weekend.

A fence is not a possible solution, nor blocking all garage access (it's a open space).

Any suggestions on how deal with this problem?

Comment: learn to like cat footprints!

Comment: Or get a used car which already has finish issues... The cats are probably doing no real damage beyond cosmetic, and realistically nobody but you looks at  the car that closely. Or keep garage doors closed, if this really bothers you. Or actively train the cats, just as you train them to stay out of the kitchen sink, if you're willing to spend the time. Or go high-tech with a motion-controlled water spray. Or paint the car in jaguar spots so the footprints are masked .... Seriously, I think you'll stop worrying about this after your first parking-lot ding.

Comment: When you say you live with 3 cats, does that mean that there are 3 cats who are members of your household who are causing the problem on your car?

Comment: Yes James. keshlam Motion Controlled water spray? Never heard about that!

Answer (score 2):

Cats do this to keep warm. Does she/ he mainly do this when your engine is still warm? It's probably just a type of heat source in there eyes. Try putting a sheet over your car just a plane cotton sheet so even if she does jump on it it wnt get scratched or you could not let them in the garage if they are inside cats. If they live in the garage well just try the sheet.

Comment: No. Cats claws will rip right through the sheet, and still scratch your car. And the sheet can scratch your car - especially if there is dust under the sheet (the dust gets pushed/dragged into the surface). So this has the potential to do double damage.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes they do lay on top of the hot hood. But most of the time they are just on top of the car where there's no heat at all. I will try this sheet idea and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to stop a cat from getting on your car is to put the car in a garage. I know this answer isn't what you are looking for.

Cats are vindictive, and if they decide to mess with your car in particular, there is no amount of booby-trapping, wrapping, or protecting your car from vindictive kitty-claws.

Theoretically you could trap/export the loose kitties to the local animal shelter.